# CSS Grid: divs are spreading out down the column not across the row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here you can see the problem. I have a div tag that has a sub-grid inside it and I want the albums (which are div tags) to go across the page and not up and down.

Here is my page where you can see my problem:

https://jeremyc2.github.io/Nightingale/index.html

I added `grid-auto-flow: row` to my css for the element, but it seems to be ignoring that altogether.

```css
.album-strip {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

Comment: add `display: grid` to `album-strip`? also you can omit `grid-auto-flow: row` as it is default...

Comment: Simple replace this css with current.

.album-strip {
    display: flex;
}

Comment: @kukkuz Thank you! That fixes it. I don't know how I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
album-strip {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```